# Action when chrome extension closing

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I've a chrome extension wich  open a new tab and inject any javascript into it.
But whenever that the extension is reloaded, it open again a new tab.
So, i want close the tabs when my extension is closed/disabled.

There is chrome.management.onDisabled, but this don't working for this extension, but for other extension. But ... perhaps the code which is injected in the tab can detect if extension is Closed ? For example, if the extension could send a message (with tab.sendMessage) when it is closing ...

Any suggestion or idea ?

Thank you very much, and excuse me for my bad english.

Comment: Is there a way to redesign the extension so that you aren't always reloading it to achieve the desired effect? The way you're describing it, it seems like it would be going against the intended use of Chrome Extensions.

Comment: Yes, i understand that is not possible for security reasons ;)
So, i've find another alternative. When the extension start, i verify if a adequat is open yet. In this case, i don't open a new tab, elseif y open a new tab ;)

Thanks for you response.